# How can I import my class in an Azure function app?

Tags: python, azure, azure-function-app

Hello guys i can't import my module in my function app, i read that i can't use from myclass import Class, so how i can import my class in my code? Test in azure portal give me cannot find module named....

[image: This is my package explore]

I have to add the classes in book,categore,user and databaseManager, how i should import it? I tried with from **app**.notify-user-function import book,user,category,databaseManager, but don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
from relative path import class name
```

For example:

If you want to import Book in book.py, below is code in book.py

```
class Book():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def bark(self):
        print(self.name + " is barking.")
```

you need to do this in `__init__.py`

```
from .book import Book
```